# Truecrypt on Android 2.2?

Tags: encryption

Has Truecrypt been ported over to Android yet?  If yes, where can I get it from as I can't seem to find it in the Market unless it's named something different.  If no, is anyone developing it? If no again, any reason why no one is developing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of people are asking that question. [Here's one](http://www.google.com.gt/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=22b231e4613fd0df&hl=en).

Some people are offering bounties. [Like at XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=872297).

Some people have [suggested](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/72980-app-similar-secubox-truecrypt.html) [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/truecrypt/?platform=android). AxCrypt looks like an alternative, and there's an alpha product that works with it (and Dropbox) called [BoxCryptor](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=29249).

But I've not found an actual port of Truecrypt to Android, nor any information about plans to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of [Cryptonite](https://code.google.com/p/cryptonite/) include an actual port of the TrueCrypt code to Android. The following restrictions apply at this time:

- No GUI - command-line access only.
- Requires FUSE. Most CyanogenMod ROMs except of Motorola builds support FUSE.
- Requires root.
- Only works with local volumes. No cloud storage support.

It's available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite) as well.
To get started, select the "expert" tab, click "Start root terminal", then use truecrypt from the command line.